# Python - by value and by reference function arguments

Tags: python, pass-by-value

Sorry if the title is not accurate, not sure how to name it properly.
the question is. If I do this code:

```
num = 1

def test_func2(arg):
    arg = 10

test_func2(num)
print(num)
```

The num will obviously stay 1
But if I do similar thing with objects

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1
        self.two = 2


test_obj = TestClass()


def test_func(arg):
    arg.one = 10

test_func(test_obj)
print(test_obj.one)
```

The value of test_obj.one will change to 10. Why are integers passed by value and user defined objects by reference?

Comment: It's a big topic about value and reference. I suggest you search more about it.

Comment: Pass by reference vs Pass by value.

Comment: @GenoChen Nope, parameters are **always** passed the same way.  Arguments refer to the same objects passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `num` refers to the integer object of value `1`.  Passing it to a function assigns `arg` to also refer to the **same** integer object of value `1`, but then `arg` is reassigned to a new integer object of value `10`.  `num` is still referring to the original integer object of value `1`.

In the second case, `test_obj` as assigned the value of a new `TestClass` instance.  Passing it to a function assigns `arg` to the **same** `TestClass` instance.  The object itself is altered, and both `arg` and `test_obj` still refer to the same object, so even after the function returns, `test_obj` "sees" the change.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that but the question is why does it work differently for a 'regular' variable and the object instance? Which section of documentation should I read to get more info on this?

Comment: @user3751086 It does't work differently.  Arguments are just new names for the same objects passed to the function, always.  In the first case, the 'arg' was reassigned to a new object.  In the second case the original object was modified and  `arg` still refers to the original object passed in.

Comment: so that means they work differently, or at lease how I understand that. Exploring the link provided above I now assume tat this behavior difference might be related to mutability of an object instance and immutability of integer. Is this correct? If yes, it explains

Comment: @user3751086 Parameter passing works the same in both cases. What you did in the function was different. You can’t mutate an immutable object, but in the second function if you’d reassigned `arg` instead of mutating its object like the first function you wouldn’t see the object change outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because -

1. In first case, after passing a variable to a function `test_func2(num)`, that value like will be caught in a local variable `arg`, whose scope is local to the function. After we return from function that variable is destroyed as the function has ended its execution.

   ```
   num = 1

   def test_func2(arg): // arg catches value 1 here
      arg = 10 // arg variable changed to 10 but this value is not reflected back to num variable
              // so num is still 1

   test_func2(num) // function called with variable
   print(num) // that's why 1 gets printed here
   ```
2. And when you pass object to the function `test_func(test_obj)`, the `arg` in function will be a reference to the object it catches i.e., `test_obj`. That means after modifying `arg.one = 10` you are actually modifying the original objects value i.e., `test_obj.one = 10`.

   ```
   def test_func(arg): // arg points to test_obj
     arg.one = 10 // actually changing test_obj.one

   test_func(test_obj) // function called with object
   print(test_obj.one) //that's why 10 gets printed here
   ```